# Last data is always displayed in ListView

Tags: android, json, listview

Here is my sample `json` result

```
[  
 {
  "ApplicationId": "1609000001",
  "Status": "Submitted"
 },
 {
  "ApplicationId": "1609000002",
  "Status": "Received"
 },
{
  "ApplicationId": "1609000004",
  "Status": "Draft"
},
]
```

I'm using `Volley` to get my `json` result. I get the values correctly but the items that is displayed on the `ListView` keeps displaying the last item for example based on the sample `json` data above is `1609000004` it returns the same value. Like how many the result is for example 3, it will display 3 `1609000004` application id.

Here's my `MainActivity`

```
 ArrayList<Notification> submissionList; 
 ListView status_lv;

 onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   status_lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.status_lv);
    statusList = new ArrayList<Notification>();

    callVolley();
    StatusAdapter adapter = new StatusAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listrow, statusList);
    status_lv.setAdapter(adapter);
   }

     private void callVolley() {
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Constants.URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                try {
                    Notification status = new Notification();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                        JSONObject submissionObj = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
  status.setApplicationId(submissionObj.getString("ApplicationId"));
  status.setStatus(submissionObj.getString("Status"));

                 statusList.add(status);      
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(req);
}
```

Upon checking inside my `for loop` I tried to put `Log` and it gets the correct datas where `ApplicationId` are 1609000001, 1609000002, 1609000004. But I don't know why it displays the last value instead in my device. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Change `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {` to `for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {`. Also initialize  `Notification status = new Notification();` in for loop.

Comment: Can u share your list adapter code

Comment: @Piyush I'm trying to display only the first 5 of the returned json result.

Comment: @mori Read my whole comment

Comment: @Piyush thank you its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add you code line

```
Notification status = new Notification();
```

inside the loop like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                        JSONObject submissionObj = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

Notification status = new Notification();
  status.setApplicationId(submissionObj.getString("ApplicationId"));
  status.setStatus(submissionObj.getString("Status"));

                 statusList.add(status);      
                    }
```

also change in the loop add "response.size" in place of i<5 otherwise you may get "outOfIndexException".

Comment: What if I wanted to get the first 5 result data ? How to do it in my for loop?

Comment: You can do this in saveral way , 
1)  first check the response.size>=5 then use 5 in the loop otherwise use respone.size .

2) use only response.size in the loop and break the loop if  "i==4" using break statement.

3) You can use one method that return List<Notification> and return if loop's i==5.

Answer (score 1):

Set adapter after for loop

```
ArrayList<Notification> submissionList; 
ListView status_lv;

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    status_lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.status_lv);

    callVolley();

}

private void callVolley() {
    statusList = new ArrayList<Notification>();

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Constants.URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                try {


                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        Notification status = new Notification();
                        JSONObject submissionObj = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                        status.setApplicationId(submissionObj.getString("ApplicationId"));
                        status.setStatus(submissionObj.getString("Status"));

                        statusList.add(status);      
                    }

                    StatusAdapter adapter = new StatusAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listrow, statusList);
                    status_lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(req);
}
```